# Solving Recurrence Equation with exponents

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

How do I solve the recurrence equation of the form:

$T(n) = n T^2(n/2)$ with initial condition $T(1) = 6$ where $n = 2^k$ for some integer $k$. The hint asks to use logarithm to convert into a linear nonhomogenous equation and then solve.

Comment: $logT(n) = log(n) + 2log(T(n/2))$. Let $S(k)=logT(2^k)$ you have $S(k)=log(k)+2(S(k-1))$ can you solve this now?

Comment: @yanko : Could you write $2\log T(n/2),$ coding it as 2\log T(n/2), instead of $2log(T(n/2))\text{ ?}$ The backslash not only prevents italicization but also results in proper spacing before and after $\log.$ Similarly $\sin,$ $\max,$ $\det,$ etc. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael, Thanks I will use it next time, I'm no longer allowed to edit that other comment.

Comment: @yanko: if we use logarithm to the base 2 then isn't log (n) equal to k rather than log (k) ?

Comment: @Aravind yes you are right and this makes the recurrence equation much easier.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the question from the list of unanswered.

For each non-negative integer $k$ put $R(k)=T(2^k)=T(n)$. Then $R(0)=6$ and if $k\ge 1$ then

$$R(k+1)=2R(k)^2=2(2R(k-1)^2)^2=2^3R(k-1)^4=\dots.$$

This suggest a conjecture $R(k)=2^{2^k-1}R(0)^{2^k}$ for each $k$, which can be easily proved by induction. Substituting, we obtain $T(n)=2^{n-1}6^n$.